# Perturbation problem equation

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have an equation:
$(1-\epsilon)x^2 -2x +1=0$ (regularly perturbed problem, we anticipate all roots to remain bounded when $\epsilon$ goes to $0$)

I substitute $x=\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq0}C_n \epsilon^n$ and have to work out the equations for $C_0,C_1,C_2$.

So I get: $C_0^2-2C_0+1=0$ so $C_0=1$

and there a problem starts: as the equation for $C_1$ is: $2C_0C_1-C_0^2-2C_1=0$ so we get $1=0$. 
What is the reason this approach fails and how to devise a way to fix it?

Comment: C_0 has one possible value, not two.

Comment: Well the equation is quadratical, so theres 2 roots

Comment: You will know the reason when you solve for the roots in terms of $\epsilon$. You will get a term with $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ and you try to write it as a power series about origin which is not possible since the derivatives at the origin are not bounded. A better way would be to replace $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon^2$ (if you know $\epsilon$ is positive) and then go about

Answer (score 5):

Let us actually solve and see what exactly happens and what is the reason for this erroneous result you get.

Solving we get $$\displaystyle x = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(1-\epsilon)}}{2(1-\epsilon)} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon} = \frac{1}{1 \mp \sqrt{\epsilon}} = 1 \pm \sqrt{\epsilon} + \epsilon \pm \sqrt{\epsilon^3} + \epsilon^2 \pm \sqrt{\epsilon^5} + \cdots$$

When we assume the perturbed solution is $x = \displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 0} c_n \epsilon^n$, we are not accounting for the fractional powers of $\epsilon$.

The problem essentially stems from our inability to represent $\frac{1}{1 \pm \sqrt{\epsilon}}$ as a taylor series about origin.

The error $1=0$ arises when you cancel off $2C_1$ with $-2C_1$. If we try to express $\frac{1}{1 \pm \sqrt{\epsilon}}$ as a taylor series, then you will find that the derivative at the origin $C_1$ is unbounded. Hence, you are canceling of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ and this is where the error creeps in and hence you get $1=0$.

To avoid this, a better way to deal with the problem would be as follows. If we know that the perturbation is positive, we can replace $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon^2$.

Now the problem becomes $$(1-\epsilon^2)x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$$ Solving, we get $$x=\frac{1}{1 \mp \epsilon} = 1 \pm \epsilon + \epsilon^2 \pm \epsilon^3 + \epsilon^4 \pm \epsilon^5 + \cdots$$